# Profiling sbt builds

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt build that takes ages. It's big and complex and it's hard to know where to start cleaning it up. It seems like sbt retains a lot of metadata about the structure of the build, with interdependencies, named tasks, scoping, and so on. With all this metadata, it seems like it would be quite easy to jump in and measure how much time each distinct task, with scope, takes. Doing this in code rather than based on log messages not only feels cleaner, but has the advantage of dealing nicely with concurrent builds and other complicated stuff that could cause the log times to be misleading.

Are there any facilities to do this currently? It doesn't feel like something we could do in a "user" build, but perhaps an SBT plugin could hook a task starter and maintain/produce a big report of timings at the end. It would really help focus my efforts on improving the slow things without wasting time on things that happen instantly.

Answer (score 3):

I had absolutely the same problem some time ago. Look at source code of https://github.com/sbt-android-mill/sbt-android-mill

Here is announce - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-on-android/TsmmJA4uvQ4/LMvAxuovXoMJ Pay attention to time field in SBT log.

Few wrappers + something like stopwatch(in dependencies) and you will have attractive HTML reports with profiling statistics.

Comment: Thanks! I tried reading the code but can't immediately understand what you're doing to make this work. Are you just defining a canonical project structure that is instrumented, or have you found a way to hook sbt so that you can time arbitrary sbt builds? My problem is that I have a huge build already in place and I would like to profile it without adding stopwatch calls to every task (including sbt's predefined ones). Does your approach handle that?

Comment: I define `totalStopwatch`, `profilingGroups` at _sbt/android/mill/Mill.scala_ and wrap my own code with `stopwatchGroup("blabla") {code}`.
I wrap generic SBT tasks with profiling (for example _sbt/android/mill/compile/Compile.scala_) like
`compile in Configurations.Compile <<= compile in Configurations.Compile dependsOn compileStageCorePre` - start stopwatch and 
`compileStageCore <<= compileStageCore dependsOn (compileStagePrepare, compile in Configurations.Compile)` - stop Stopwatch. It is one line tasks at bottom of _Compile.scala_
Pay attention to `taskPre` and `taskPost` method.

Comment: If you have really complex projects IMHO it is better to spent some time to add profiling and optimize it that waste time month after month.

Comment: 5 cents more. I found that is very handy to create project hierarchy even for solid projects. Scala multi-thread compilation is weak, but each subproject is compiled in parallel.
I asked about parallel compilation in SBT mailing list, but there is no way to optimize. As side effect you provide better modularity inside single module.