# How to profile the time spent for a task in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to know why sometimes my build is much slower.

So I've decided to measure the time of long-running taks.

When running pure Scala code, it is quite easy to do so:

```
def myMethod() = {
   val initTime = System.currentTimeMillis
   ...
   val elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis-initTime
}
```

But for tasks like `packageBin` or `compile`, whose source code I cannot change, I don't know how to measure it, because I cannot control when `someTask.value` is run.

Any hint?

Related questions:

- [Profiling sbt builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221059/profiling-sbt-builds)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a more complete analysis, you can also use [**`jrudolph/sbt-optimizer/`**](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-optimizer/)

> `sbt-optimizer` is an experimental plugin that hooks into sbt's task execution engine and offers a graphical ASCII report once a tree of tasks has been run
>
> Add the plugin to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-optimizer" % "0.1.2")
```

> and enable it in a project with:

```
enablePlugins(net.virtualvoid.optimizer.SbtOptimizerPlugin)
```

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrudolph/sbt-optimizer/master/docs/example-line.png]

> Each output line corresponds to one task that has been executed.
>
> - The first time is the total time this task was running.
> - The second time displayed in green is the actual execution time.
> - The third time displayed in red is time the task wanted to run but was waiting for the global ivy lock.
> - The last time displayed in cyan is the time the task was blocked waiting for Ivy downloads.

Answer (score 21):

add `-Dsbt.task.timings=true` to your JAVA_OPTS when launching sbt

Comment: Really an easy solution!
The number formatting is really ugly: ` {file:/home/d/rds/project/}rds-build/compile:resources: 0.015903999999999998 ms`

Comment: There are few more options related to this. The main one I use is `-Dsbt.task.timings.on.shutdown=false` to get feedback after the task is run instead of when the JVM shuts down. You can see more on `sbt.internal.TaskTimings` (although note that there is a type in `-Dsbt.task.timing=true`, it is missing the `s`)