# How can I debug an sbt-coursier hang-on-startup issue?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

How can I debug an `sbt-coursier` hang-on-startup issue?  (Note, I'm also using `sbt-assembly`.)

I would really like to use `sbt-coursier`, but it's just not working for me. Platform is Windows 10, I hope that's not why.  What's odd is that even though `sbt-coursier` supposedly no longer uses the dreadful `.sbt.ivy.lock` file, I still see it appear when I am using `sbt-coursier`.  It's almost as though `sbt-couriser` is waiting on it ...*forever*..., but that doesn't make sense to me, because I thought in recent versions `sbt-coursier` completely moved away from using `.sbt.ivy.lock`.

When I try to use the `sbt-cousier` plugin, my `sbt` session hangs during startup.

```
// This is file:  ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.1.0-M10")

// console output
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from build.sbt,idea.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea6673.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\me\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/me/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] Loading settings for project myapp-build from assembly.sbt ...
```

If I go back to *not* using `sbt-coursier`, everything is fine.

```
// This is file:  ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/build.sbt
// addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.1.0-M10")

// console output
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from build.sbt,idea.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from idea62602.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\me\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/me/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading settings for project myapp-build from assembly.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\me\Documents\C\IdeaProjects\MyApp\project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/C/IdeaProjects/MyApp/project/"), "myapp-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] Loading settings for project myapp from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to myapp (in build file:/C:/Users/me/Documents/C/IdeaProjects/MyApp/)
[IJ]sbt:myapp>
```

Comment: Did you try to profile sbt and see which task takes most of time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588234/how-to-profile-the-time-spent-for-a-task-in-sbt

Comment: and running with `sbt --debug` ?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks @IvanStanislavciuc !

Comment: It produced a lot of output, now seems to have stopped right after: [debug] Copy resource mappings:

Comment: It's been a half hour, it's still hung at: [debug] Copy resource mappings:

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?