# Scala Sbt - Measure task time for subprojects

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

We do have a Scala-Sbt-Project with a lot subprojects.

Usually, we call the `compile` or `test` task on the root (aggregate).
I am searching for a way, how to get an overview for the used time of the tasks for each subproject.

Because (especially the tests) are to too slow (4,5 hours), I want to see, which subprojects are so slow. I am interested especially in the compile an test phase.
Does anybody have a hint?

Is there a hidden functionality in sbt or in scalatest, or is there a good plugin anywhere to find out where all the time got eaten?

Would be really nice to have an overview with the used time after all projects finished the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [configuring reporter](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#configuringReporters) to show test duration with `D` flag, for example

```
Test / testOptions += Tests.Argument("-oD")
```

prints using standard output reporter

```
[info] ExampleSpec:
[info] The config map
[info] - should contain target directory used by sbt (18 milliseconds)
```

Note the `(18 milliseconds)`.

Also consider [How to profile the time spent for a task in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588234/how-to-profile-the-time-spent-for-a-task-in-sbt). For example, in the project root create `.jvmopts` file with entry

```
-Dsbt.task.timings=true
```

Comment: `-Dsbt.task.timings=true` gives a good overview over the spend time. Thanks for the hint. Will accept this answer, because of this flag.

Still a bit sad, that I can't see the results grouped for each subproject.

Comment: Maybe this is useful for other user: An overview of other command line parameters:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html