# Profile Scala3 compiler

Tags: scala, compilation, scala-3, scala-metals

We have one Scala3 project where we use macros. We use Visual Studio Code with Metals plugin.

`sbt clean compile`

tooks more then 20 minutes. Is there any way to profile Scala3
compiler to figure out where that time goes?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the compilerflag "-Vprofile" in your `build.sbt`.

```
scalacOptions += "-Vprofile"
```

It will output the complexity of your files. At least, it will give you a hint, where a lot of compile time will be spend.

Maybe this will be interesting for you as well:
[Scala Sbt - Measure task time for subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275728/scala-sbt-measure-task-time-for-subprojects)